# Connection refused between containers: Docker

Tags: docker

i am new to docker and was trying to connect two docker containers. I pulled a Redis image and ran it:

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name redis1 redis
```

After that i used "docker exec" to add some content in the redis container:

```
docker exec -it redis1 sh
redis-cli
set name surya
incr counter
```

After that i created a new container using the same redis image and tried accessing the first redis container:

```
docker run -it --rm --link redis1:redis --name client redis sh
redis-cli -h redis
```

Now, instead of connecting to redis1 container i am getting an connection refused error.

> Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show what you see with the command `docker ps`? I've followed your commands and succeeded. Please check this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Af5wpzU

Comment: Hello, please check the screenshot for my "docker ps" output: https://imgur.com/WkSUaaQ

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to connect to it's own redis?

if you are trying to connect to the one you first created it should be:

`redis-cli -h redis1`

it is working fine on my local machine.

Comment: No. When  I am linking i gave the redis1 to be called as redis inside the client container.

Comment: i executed exactly same commands you provided and it is working fine on my docker machine. can you provide `docker ps` output and `docker logs redis1` ?

Comment: Hi, here is the output for "docker logs redis1": https://imgur.com/S3QIxmr
output for "docker ps": https://i.imgur.com/WkSUaaQ.png

Comment: it shows connection aborted due to said reason.. I suggest to delete your redis:latest image and pull it back and run the same command.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/45#issuecomment-182599683 .

You could use docker-compose when trying to connect from one container to another.